Fastest way to compare two columns using like in two differents tables in MYSQL, half millions rows
I have a MYSQL database with a table 'product', about 500 000 rows, with a column 'oem' (varchar 255, utf8_unicode_ci). I have another table 'oem' with a column 'oem' too (varchar 255, utf8_unicode_ci), about 150 000 rows.
I need to search all products with "messy" oem to export them in csv file, in order to import and correct them in another app later. Messy mean that i have a lot of product with oem that are in fact for example the concatenation of two or more correct oem, sometimes separated a space, sometime by a comma, sometimes by nothing...
To do that, i try to compare these product.oem with oem from table 'oem' that contains correct oem. I want to select products from table 'product' with (product.oem) containing an oem from table 'oem', but only when oem don't match exactly, because if they do, it meant the product.oem is correct and i don't want it in my csv file.
Example :
product 1 oem : ABBA is selected because is containing 'BB' that match exactly an oem from table oem;
And i don't want to select product with oem that match exactly an oem in table oem :
Example :
product 2 oem : BAAB is not selected because is containing 'BAAB' that match an oem in table oem;
So i did this simple SQL query using 'like' :
SELECT p.* 
FROM product p 
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM oem 
    WHERE p.oem LIKE CONCAT('%', oem.oem, '%') 
        AND p.oem != oem.oem 
    ) AND p.id > 0 
ORDER BY p.id ASC 
LIMIT 5000;

This works in my local environment but it's so slow i had to reduce the limit number to 5000. I have indexes on column p.id (PRIMARY), p.oem and oem.oem. It doesn't work in production (same data), 503 service unavailable after very long processing.
I also tried join query :
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
JOIN oem
    ON p.oem LIKE CONCAT('%', oem.oem, '%')
WHERE p.oem != oem.oem
    AND p.id > 0
ORDER BY p.id ASC
LIMIT 5000;

It is 10 times worse.
So my question is, what is the best way to achieve what i am trying to do here ? Thanks

The problem is the leading wildcard before the oem.oem expression. It prevents the index from being any help and GREATLY increases the comparison complexity.

I have the feeling this question would have a different answer if you provided actual example data.  As is, this is not a good fit to do in SQL; I would do this in a client.

@JoelCoehoorn Yes but i don't know how to do without it.

Do you really need AND p.id > 0?

@RickJames it's for batch process. I process 5000 rows by 5000 rows. I keep the last processed id in a table and I used it here (it's 0 for the first process, then the last processed id each time). So yes I need it in my case.

@Yannrog - OK, does this mean that the table gets bigger and bigger?

WHERE p.oem LIKE CONCAT('%', oem.oem, '%')  AND p.oem != oem.oem is a partial match but not an exact match?  That seems strange.

@RickJames I will explain a little bit of context : The products in the product table have "messy" oem, like for example the concatenation of two or more oem, sometimes separated a space, sometime by a comma, sometimes by nothing... I want to detect them with my table oem which is my table of reference oem. This is why i don't want to select products with oem that match exactly oem in that table of oem of reference, because they are already good, i don't need to correct them.

Its an unusual requirement to search for a substring of OEMs.
I would create a new table with primary keys of the product and the OEM, then populate this table by running your search for each product (as I assume there will be multiple results for each product)
As its such a slow operation, you can populate this table slowly, and in batches so it won't break the transaction log. eg you run the search for product 1, then product 2, writing the results to the table separately each time. It will take ages (as will any query you come up with that does substring matches) but you'll then have a lookup table to refer to repeatedly afterwards.

Thanks for you reply. I can't do one product at a time, because it mean doing it 500 000 times which is impossible for the user. But i do it in batches and rather than saving in another table, i save results in csv file. I save progression in another table (last id processed).

The csv file is fine, but youy might as well save it to a new table, then you can query it easier and see the last id processed just by reading the max id value. At some point I think you might want to rationalise the original data, and the new table would be the perfect place for this.

I don't see the point of another table here because what I need in the end is a CSV file with all the columns in table product. Theses csv files will then be used to import and correct products in another app. If I do a new table, I will still have to do very slow join between this new table and the product table.

May I suggest this as a better way to "chunk" the processing:
    WHERE  pid BETWEEN $left_off AND $left_0ff + 5000
      ABD  ,,,

This keeps the number of rows per chunk looked at to a minimum—possibly less than 5000—rather than occasionally running to the end of the table.
I would suggest 1000 instead of 5000 -- to further limit the impact on other processing, without significantly impacting the processing.
After those changes, time both the EXISTS and JOIN approaches.
Also, let's avoid doing the EXISTS over and over...

Is using between more efficient than the using p.id > x, order by and limit ? Thanks

@Yannrog - When there are not 5000 rows matching that CONCAT before the end of the table and there a million rows left in the table, that is very inefficient.
